# Duplicate meta tags issue despite having "rel='canonical'" tag

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, canonical-url, meta-tags, rel-canonical

I'm getting more and more duplicate meta tags alerts on Google Webmaster tools everyday. It's a blog and I have setup `rel='canonical'` tags long before and they are showing up correctly.

- `http://www.example.com/` (Canonical)
- `http://www.example.com/?m=1`

I have checked out the instructions from the blog posts below and made sure that there's no issue in the implementation of the tag.

- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html
- https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/rel-canonical-html-head/

I'm wondering what could the reason be?

Comment: Might need an example to look at here.